# how to get .value_count and values in single data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my sample csv

```
    ID DESC 
1    1 Car
2    2 Boat
3    3 Bike
4    4 Car
5    5 Car
6    6 Car
7    7 Car
```

When I do `.value_counts()` I get

```
5
1
1
```

I want to get

```
ID DESC COUNT
1  Car  5
2  Boat 1
3  Bike 1
```

This is my current attempt

```
import pandas as pd

path = "C:\Matching_Desc.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(path, encoding= 'unicode_escape')

df2 = df['DESC'].value_counts().index.tolist()

df3 = df['DESC'].value_counts()

df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df3)

df3.columns = ['COUNT']
df2.columns = ['DESC']

frames = [df2,df3]

result = pd.concat(frames)

result.to_csv("C:\matching.csv", index=False)
```

This does not concat the two df properly and does not have the ID

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why ID 1/2/3? Is this the ID of the first match?

Comment: It is the ID of each DESC. Think of it like an identifier that I can use to clean up my data. But that ID is unique to each DESC. 1,2,3 is the example but in reality ID is more like a serial number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `groupby.agg` in place of `value_counts`:

```
(df.groupby('DESC', as_index=False, sort=False)
   .agg(**{'ID': ('ID', 'first'),
           'COUNT': ('ID', 'size')
           })
 )
```

Output:

```
   DESC  ID  COUNT
0   Car   1      5
1  Boat   2      1
2  Bike   3      1
```